# Maven module jars not added to war lib

Tags: maven

I have multi-module Maven project:

```
Parent 
  Core module
  Web module
  War Module
```

And in War's POM I added the dependency of Web and Core:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.team.hello</groupId>
        <artifactId>helloParent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>hello-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>hello-war Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.team.hello</groupId>
            <artifactId>hello-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.team.hello</groupId>
            <artifactId>hello-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>hello-war</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingIcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingIcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

and in Web's `pom.xml` I added the dependency of Core module.

While building using `clean -e install` I am seeing two jars in War's `lib` folder but, while publishing to jboss-eap it is copying only Web's `jar` file to `lib` folder but not Core's `jar` file.

Could you tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: If you open the war, what's in it?

Comment: all the maven dependent jar files and hello-web-0-0-1-snapshot.jar file in lib folder, views etc. But hello-core-0-0-1-sapshot.jar is not copied to lib folder

Comment: `packagingIcludes` has a typo, it should be `packagingIncludes`. But why use that in the first place? Remove it, let `maven-war-plugin` do its job.

Comment: While building the war using clean -e install it is generating the archive war file and everything is good(core and web jars copied to lib folder). But when I am adding into jboss using eclipse-->jboss server--> **add and remove**  the core jar is not getting published to lib folder but web jar is getting published.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution. I removed the pluginmanagement and then deleted .settings and .project of war module and then reimported the projects(checked the deployed assembly it has both core and web and maven) the cleaned the jboss eclipse(in eclipse jboss server--right click-->clean) then it published the jar.